# Which response status code goes to catchError in Angular 6+ httpClient?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

In Angular 6+ httpClient, a request can be configured to get the entire response.

The response observable can be piped into `map` and `catchError` operators.

When does the execution go through the `map` operator and when to `catchError`?

Does it depend on responce status code?

For example, if `response.status === 200` then go to `map`, else go to `catchError`?

If not only status 200 goes to `map`, then which else?

And which statuses go to `catchError`?

```js
getData(): Observable<[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
        map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {  
            return response.status === 200;
        }),
        catchError((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) =>
            // which value may be logged here?
            console.log(errorResponse.status);
            of(false);
        ));
}
```

Comment: 4xx and 5xx status codes are errors. The other ones are success. https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details

Comment: JB Nizet, that is what I was looking for. Move your comment to answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4xx and 5xx status codes are errors. The other ones are success.

http://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details